# How to call a webmethod to accept POST

Tags: c#, web-services, post

I need to post data to my backend  via a webservice.

My webmethod is ;

```
[WebMethod]

    public string InsertData(string dData)
    {
        Log.Info(deviceData);
        ....
        string status= serv.InsertData(dData);
        return status;
    }
```

From fiddler if I call using POST verb , it gives

> Request Format is invalid

**My Requirement**

Please let me know how should this be called via POST.

GET is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static string Example(string id)
 {
    return "it worked";
 }
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> true if the method is invoked by using the HTTP GET command; false if
>   the method is invoked by using the HTTP POST command. The default is
>   false.

Default is false so you should be already using POST.

About calling it,
try from jquery:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/Example",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'theIdToPass'
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                alert("complete: " + status + "\n\nResponse: " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    </script>
```